# How can I bind data in ngFor?

Tags: html, angular

I have a problem in input text, when I write in one input it changes in the other input as well ! how can I fix that !
HTML code:

```
  <mat-expansion-panel  class="childPanel" [expanded]="true" hideToggle disabled style=" background:#F2EDFF;" *ngFor="let i of listSousCategorie"   >
            <div class="childPanel_body2 mat-badge-large" fxLayout="row" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="start center"  >
              <div style="padding-left:1em" fxFlex="grow" >{{i.libelle}} {{i.id}}</div>
              <mat-form-field  >
                <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(i.id)">
                <mat-label>Note</mat-label>
                <input  type="text" matInput  formControlName="Note" [(ngModel)]="Note" >
              </form>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
```

TS Code:

```
Note:string;

     ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          Note: [''],
        });
      }
    
              onSubmit(id:number) {
                  let obj = this.form.value;
                  obj.Note = this.Note;
            
                  console.log(this.Note)
                  this.LExamenSousCategorieService.updateSouCategorie(obj,id).then(res => {
                  })
                }
```

[image]

Comment: listSousCategorie what is that

Comment: @vaira its list of object contains  ` {id: "69", id_categorie: "1", code: "1", libelle: "science", coefficient: "2", Note: null }..... `

Comment: is it even array

Comment: You bind all inputs to the same model (all habe the same ngModel)

Comment: @vaira yes ! I added a pic to  my question you can check it plz

Comment: @Deitsch yes , but how can I fix it !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you bind note and why do you use a formGroup (you should do either or and not both btw)?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms

Comment: @Deitsch I want to update Note in every i of listSousCategorie ! yes I used at first ngModel it didnt work the I added the form group !! same problem that the value of the input keep changing in every input

Comment: The problem is you bind every input to the same formControl/ngModel. What do you mean by `update Note in every i of listSousCategorie`

Comment: One question do you want to update every note form individually or a single submit for to sav all the notes